# Cannot process large pdf file (100M plus) when using jMagick in java

Tags: java, performance, image-processing, imagemagick, jmagick

I am using jMagick for java to process uploaded files (images and pdf files). Most images work fine but when I tried to convert large multiple-page pdf files to different size of images, it  consumes very large amount of system memory (about 20G physical memory for a 200M pdf files), and failed eventually. I am setting the density to 200 since otherwise the image quality is very bad that I cannot even read the words in the output images. Below is the code I have:

```
  ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(inputFilePath);
  info.setDensity(200);
  MagickImage image = new MagickImage(info);
  MagickImage[] imageFrames = image.breakFrames();
  for (MagickImage frame : imageFrames) {
    ImageInfo frameInfo = new ImageInfo();
    MagickImage frameDisplay = frame;
    frameDisplay.setFileName(outputFile);
    frameDisplay.writeImage(frameInfo);
  }
```

There is no error or exception in my java log, I just see the process died. I have tried to use policy.xml in /usr/share/ImageMagick-6.5.4/config/ to limit the memory usage as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policymap [
<!ELEMENT policymap (policy)+>
<!ELEMENT policy (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST policy domain (delegate|coder|filter|path|resource) #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy name CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy rights CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy pattern CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST policy value CDATA #IMPLIED>
]>

<policymap>
    <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MB"/>
</policymap>
```

But somehow it does not seem to work. I am using ImageMagick-6.5.4. Really appreciate any advice!

Comment: "Does not work" meaning ....

Comment: The JVM restarted, not any image saved from the pdf which needs to be converted

Comment: "The JVM restarted"? What??? Do you mean your program crashed? If so, stacktrace please

Comment: And please update your question with the information requested :). You provided a fine description of what you are doing but you are missing the information what goes wrong.

Comment: Sure sorry for the confusion. I are using weblogic, so the only thing we have in the log is the weblogic node for this particular JVM got restarted. At the meantime, when I tried to just run the convert command from the command line with same 200m file, the process was killed by the OS after a few minutes without any error messages, while I can see the 30G free memory dropped to about 100M during that processing time.

Comment: Can't you adjust your code so ImageMagick only considers one page per time instead of the whole file at once ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<policymap>
    <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MB"/>
</policymap>
```

Try updating this section to:

```
<policymap>
    <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="1000MB"/>
</policymap>
```

and try again.  I'm presuming when you said 'The JVM restarted', you mean that it crashed.  Probably an `OutOfMemory` exception.  No one can say for sure with the information you've provided.

Comment: Thx, let me try that. I was thinking it should be JVM OutOfMemory exception as well, which is why I am setting the JVM as: 

-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m

But that seems even make the problem worse. The java process still took 30G memory and event crashed the linux server. That is why I want to limit the physical memory use even it means the image will be in VM so maybe gonne be slow quite a bit.

Comment: @Amir my suspicion as well